# Getting a null Array from a method

Tags: arrays, android-studio, null

I've created a method that shall return a two-dimensional Array, everything works perfectly as the array is being correctly filled in the method's `try`. 
But once I display the array on `onCreate()`, it's returning null.

```
public class ListTickets extends AppCompatActivity {


    public String[][] ticketTab ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_tickets);

        ticketTab = new String[Integer.valueOf(nbTicket)][nbTicketTab];


        DisplayArray(getTicketsHTTP());


    }

        private String[][] getTicketsHTTP() {


        final JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray Jdata = response.getJSONArray("data");
                            for (int i=0; i < Jdata.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject oneTicket = Jdata.getJSONObject(i);

                                    titreTicket = oneTicket.getString("1");
                                    slaTicket = oneTicket.getString("30");
                                    dateDebutTicket = oneTicket.getString("15");
                                    urgenceTicket = oneTicket.getString("10");
                                    statutTicket = oneTicket.getString("12");
                                    idTicket = oneTicket.getString("2");


                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e("Err", e.getMessage());
                                }


                                ticketTab[i][0] = titreTicket;
                                ticketTab[i][1] = slaTicket;
                                ticketTab[i][2] = dateDebutTicket;
                                ticketTab[i][3] = urgenceText(urgenceTicket);
                                ticketTab[i][4] = calculTempsRestant(dateDebutTicket, slaTicket, dateEchanceTicket);
                                ticketTab[i][5] = String.valueOf(ticketEnretard);
                                ticketTab[i][6] = statutTicket;
                                ticketTab[i][7] = idTicket;


                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Log.e("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    }

                }
        ){
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("App-Token",FirstEverActivity.App_Token);
                params.put("Session-Token",session_token);
                return params;
            }

        };

        // add it to the RequestQueue
        queue.add(getRequest);

        return ticketTab;
    }


}
```

I declared ticketTab outside the `onCreate` because when I declare it inside the method, I cannot change it inside the `try`.
How can I return the array correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In your onCreate you are using this line:

```
ticketTab = new String[Integer.valueOf(nbTicket)][nbTicketTab];
```

and those values, `nbTicket` and `nbTicketTab` are not declared anywhere in your code, maybe that's why they are returning null, you have to initialize them and asign values.

Comment: I removed them from the code to make it clearer. I've initialized them. The problem was coming from the JSON Request, it works in a asynchronous  way, means that you never know when the `onResponse()` method is gonna be invoked. So it was returning a null array before even filling it because the `onResponse()` was not invoked yet.